# Flutter tree intends guides suddenly disappeared

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea

I'm on Flutter version 2.10.2, Dart 2.16.1 using IntelliJ Ultimate latest version, it was showing normally and one day it suddenly disappeared and I couldn't get them back again. I made sure "show indent guides" is checked in IntelliJ settings.

**This is how my code looks now:**

[image]

I tried opening the same project on both VS Code and Android Studio and its not working on there too, but opening a new project sometimes shows the guides.

Answer (score 0):

Go to editors setting, search for guides, make sure the checkbox is marked, then restart the editor once. Hopefully problem will get resolved.

Comment: I have mentioned in my post that I made sure ui guides is checked and enabled

Comment: I had the same issue earlier, then I removed the flutter extension from the editor then once again checked ui guides and restarted the editor and problem got solved..

Comment: Siddiq barbhuiya, I tried that multiple times and did not work for me.